# Why isn't postgres 14 pulling the latest data after upgrade (using heroku pg:pull)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I use heroku pg:pull to update the db on my local machine (I drop it and pull it from heroku each time I want to update it). This was working fine before my upgrade to PG14.

My production DB on heroku is running version 13.4

After upgrading to postgres 14 on my local machine, heroku pg:pull still works, but it wont  pull the last ~10 days worth of data (which is roughly when I upgraded)...it is as though the db won't pull anything that was created on the production DB after my upgrade on my local machine.

There is new data being added to the production db on heroku, and all of the old data is pulled fine (data that was created on production before my upgrade to PG14), but the latest data that is pulled is from around Oct 10th (date of upgrade) and nothing created on the production DB after that date is pulled.

Is there a new setting or flag in postgres 14 that I need to add in order to pull ALL of the data (including data that was created after my upgrade?).

I am using rails 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual box VM.

Comment: Are you sure that you are pulling from the same database? Maybe the database was changed on Heroku recently and you are pulling from an old database that is no longer being committed too?

Comment: Yes. I only have one database on heroku, running postgres 13.4